# Java applet trying to fetch more than in archive list

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, applet

I browse to a JSP on my server (running JBoss 4.0.4). That jsp contains the code:

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet"
            archive="a.jar,b.jar,c.jar"

    ...
</jsp:plugin>
```

When I look at my access log, I can see a.jar, b.jar, and c.jar being fetched, but I also see a lot of 404s for requests for things that are not in the archive list, for example xerces.jar, jta1.0.1.jar, and others.

The applet behaves correctly. I wondering whether this is caused by one of the classes in a.jar/b.jar/c.jar making reference to a xerces class, but that can't be right as it would not know to request xerces.jar as it wouldn't know where the class should be.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the jars probably references the xerces, jta jars through the `Class-Path` entry of its manifest.

Quote from [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Overview):

> Originally, an applet class loader uses a simple linear search
>   algorithm to search each element on its internal search path, which is
>   constructed from the "ARCHIVE" tag or the "Class-Path" main attribute.